# How to get a String array to equal another String array

Tags: java, arrays

```
String[] mySecret;
String[] colours = {"R","Y","Bl","G","O","Pu","Pi","Br"};

public void getuserInput() {
    numColours = min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max-min) +1));
    numPegs = min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max-min) +1));
}
public void setSecret() {
    for (i=0; i<numColours; i++) {
        mySecret[i] = colours[new Random().nextInt(colours.length)];
    }
}
```

This is a small part of my code. When I run this, I get a NullPointerException. Is there any other way to get mySecret which is meant to be a string array to contain a specified number of colours but chosen at random from the colours string array. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud initialize your array `mySecret`  like this:

```
 String[] colours = {"R","Y","Bl","G","O","Pu","Pi","Br"};
 String[] mySecret = new String[colours.length];
```

Comment: The OP wants `numColours` entries in `mySecret`, not `colours.length`. See: `for (i=0; i<numColours; i++) { mySecret[i] =`

Comment: Thanks, this worked, with the term new in front of String. However I was wondering the class this code currently is in extends another class(Board). In the other class I have already defined *String[ ] mySecret;*, so I thought it would be unnecessary to define it again in this class. However I did not specify the array length.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on the Java language a bit more.

```
public void setSecret() {
    mySecret = new String[numColours];
    for ( int i=0; i<numColours; i++) {
        mySecret[i] = colours[new Random().nextInt(colours.length)];
    }
}
```